# Sever tag not well formed while using hidden field?

Tags: asp.net, repeater, hidden-field

I am using a hidden field inside repeater and try to bind it with menuid,so that i can retrieve the menuid from serverside.

But somehow i am getting the following error

```
Server Tag is not well formed
```

The hidden field i have used in the repeater is as follows

```
<ul class="navBar" id="jsddm">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptHeaderMenu" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <li>
                     <a href="<%#Eval("MENU_URL") %>"><%#Eval("MENU_NAME") %></a>
   Hidden Filed =>   <asp:HiddenField ID="hFiledHdrMenuId" runat="server" Value="<%#Eval("MENU_ID") %>"  />        
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptChildMenu" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<%#Eval("MENU_URL") %>"><%#Eval("MENU_NAME") %></a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater> 
                    </li>                       
            </ItemTemplate>                
         </asp:Repeater>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Use single quote instead of double for server controls `<asp:HiddenField ID="hFiledHdrMenuId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("MENU_ID") %>'  />        `

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try below code
You need to use single quote for server control to bind data

```
<ul class="navBar" id="jsddm">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptHeaderMenu" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <li>
                     <a href="<%#Eval("MENU_URL") %>"><%#Eval("MENU_NAME") %></a>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hFiledHdrMenuId" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("MENU_ID") %>'  />        
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptChildMenu" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<%#Eval("MENU_URL") %>"><%#Eval("MENU_NAME") %></a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater> 
                    </li>                       
            </ItemTemplate>                
         </asp:Repeater>
     </ul>
```

Comment: Here when i put double quotes in anchor tags its working properly.Why is it so ?

Comment: Because it is not a server control. When you put `runat="server"` tag then you need to use single quote

Answer (score 0):

You need to use single quote for server control to bind data

```
<ul class="navBar" id="jsddm">
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptHeaderMenu" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>                    
                    <li>
                     <a href='<%#Eval("MENU_URL") %>'>
                        <%#Eval("MENU_NAME") %>
                     </a>
   <asp:HiddenField ID="hFiledHdrMenuId" runat="server" 
                                     Value='<%#Eval("MENU_ID") %>'  />        
                        <asp:Repeater ID="rptChildMenu" runat="server">
                            <HeaderTemplate>
                                <ul>
                            </HeaderTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <li>
                                    <a href='<%#Eval("MENU_URL") %>'>
                                        <%#Eval("MENU_NAME") %>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                </ul>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                        </asp:Repeater> 
                    </li>                       
            </ItemTemplate>                
         </asp:Repeater>
     </ul>
```